# Unity Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Tags: c#, time, unity-game-engine, void

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Pause : MonoBehaviour {
bool paus;

void wait()
{
    if(paus == 0)
    {
        Time.timeScale == 0F;
    }

    if(paus == 1)
    {
        Time.timeScale == 1.0F;
    }
    paus= !paus;
```

Comment: On which line exactly? Have you ever search your error message on Google? Are you sure you _really_ understand the code you write?

Comment: Yes I do but it's on Time.timescale = 0F; and Time.timeScale == 1.0F; I have been reading all the articles i could find but they were with totally different examples and code and didn't know how to apply it to my own. Please, if you could help me.

Comment: What are `Time` and `timeScale` exactly? Can you show their implementation as well?

Comment: Whay do you mean by that exactly? Do you mean I should write what time and timeScale are used for?

Comment: @Gaximaran `==` is used for comparison. If you want to assign a value, use a single `=`.

Comment: Oh my god hahaha I didn't notice that thanks for pointing it out to me :)

Comment: Btw you can't compare a `bool` to `int`. `if(paus == 0)` isn't a valid c# code.

Comment: Please, red tag descriptions before using them.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can't compare bool to int. (in if statement)
2. You use equality operator "==" ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx)) to assign value to variable. Use an assignment  operator "=" ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx))

After fixing your code it's may look like this:

```
if(paus)
{
    Time.timeScale = 0F;
}

if(paus == 1)
{
    Time.timeScale = 1.0F;
}
paus= !paus;
```